# Convert x,y,z origin of SRS to longitude and latitude and place on map

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, mapping

I have a file with this metadata -

```
<ModelMetadata version="1">
<!--Spatial Reference System-->
<SRS>EPSG:32636+5773</SRS>
<!--Origin in Spatial Reference System-->
<SRSOrigin>700137,3489675,0</SRSOrigin>
<Texture>
    <ColorSource>Visible</ColorSource>
</Texture>
```

I try to place the point of the SRS on map.

During the search of how to do this I encounter several question :

1. I notice The EPSG combined from two number- 32636+5773 i don't understand what represent the summation of them.
   I figure out that one represent horizontal system coordinate (32636) and one represent vertical (5773)
   but I don't understand the meaning of the summation and most important how I relate it when I  configure the system coordinate I work with on the map.
2. The SRS origin is in format of x,y,z vector. How can I transform it to longitude and latitude format in order to find this location in map like Google maps?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

You have a compound coordinate reference system (CRS). EPSG::32636 represents the horizontal coordinate reference system, WGS 84 / UTM zone 36 North. This is a projected, rather than a geodetic coordinate system, but it's based on WGS 84, a geodetic coordinate reference system. EPSG::5773 is a vertical coordinate reference system, EGM96 height.

It's not an xyz vector but xy (actually easting,northing) plus H, geoidal height. If you're working with a 2D display or map then you only need to place the xy coordinates in EPSG:32636. Other data would need to be already in this CRS or would need to be projected and/or transformed to it.

Comment: I would call it a compound CRS.  2.5-D I leave to where the data only has 2D but is draped over a 3D surface.